# How do I force Remote Desktop Connection to accept user's changed username?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Windows 7 Pro, 64 bit system. 
Local users only.
At some point in the past (at least 2-4 times), the primary user of the target system changed the username.

The system does have a password, which is required to access the desktop at startup. That login requires the username 'Jim'.

When I use the Remote Desktop Connection client from another Win 7 Pro, x64 system (on the same local network), 'Jim' doesn't work. Instead I have to use the name 'User' (which was what was used way back when the system was first installed).

How do I fix this, short of wipe and re-install or creating a new user?

EDIT: I removed references to another 'working' system, as further research tells me that it did NOT ever have a name changes.

Comment: Are you sure the _username_ was changed, and not merely the "full name"? Local logins accept both, RDP only accepts the username.

Comment: So are these local or domain user we are talking about?

Comment: @Ramhound - Local users.

Comment: @gawity - control panel -> User Accounts -> Change your account name. Which I believe is the same procedure used on both systems I discussed. Is there something else I should be doing? Note again that the problem system DOES allow you to login locally using the changed name.

Comment: What users exactly have been created on each machine and which user profiles exist on each machine?

Comment: This isn't as simple as selecting Options and then changing the User Name field from the General tab to the new username, or perhaps right-click edit and then make that change and then save, or perhaps needing to select User another account, is it? If it's an RDP saved icon, or a saved shortcut click, etc. these steps may help; just change once, then each subsequent time, it'll use the new User Name. Otherwise, confirm the local account exist on the machine that doesn't all RDP access, and login from the local console to confirm it works that way, if not, then. . .

Comment: Other quick things to check are leading and trailing spaces in the user name value in case there's a blank space you cannot see, or perhaps try with all lower and upper case for the user name although I didn't think the local Window user account username are case sensitive.  Quick thoughts for simple suggestions just in case.

Comment: I've discussed this with another engineer. As far as he knows, 'yep, that's what it does'. And the only way to fix it is to add a new user with the desired name, and remove the old one. Why the changed username works locally, and not remotely is a mystery to both of us, but it appears that it's just how it is.